# Docker - Give a variable to docker-compose

Tags: docker

I have a docker-compose.yml

```
php-fpm:
    build: ./php
    container_name: php-fpm-symfony
    links:
        - db
    ports:
        - 9000:9000
        - 8000:8000
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
    volumes:
        - ../:/var/www/html
    volumes_from:
        - data
    tty: true
    env_file:
        - ./docker.env
    entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh
```

When I'm executing my `docker-compose up -d` I would like to pass an argument, which is my container name, to name dynamically my container.

**Is it possible with docker-compose?**

Like for example:

```
docker-compose up -d "-variable=symfony" // ???
```

And:

```
php-fpm:
    build: ./php
    container_name: php-fpm-$(variable)
```

Something which works like that...

Comment: Can't you just use normal environment variables?  https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: @StephenHarris But I don't necessarily want my variable to be in my container. I just want to build different container name regarding the argument.

Comment: Can't you do `container_name: php-fpm-${FOOBAR}` and then `FOOBAR=symfony docker-compose ...` ?

Comment: Apparently not. I have this message `WARNING: The FOOBAR variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.`

Comment: Did you type it on one line, 'cos it worked for me.    `% grep FOO docker-compose.yml
    container_name: foo-${FOOBAR}
% FOOBAR=hellotest docker-compose up
Recreating foo-
Attaching to foo-hellotest
foo-hellotest | Hello, World
foo-hellotest exited with code 0
`.  We can see the 'hellotest' coming from the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define all of your possible choices in YAML and use YAML references to keep the verbosity down.

```
default-container: &default-container
    build: ./php
    container_name: default
    links:
        - db
    ports:
        - 9000:9000
        - 8000:8000
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
    volumes:
        - ../:/var/www/html
    volumes_from:
        - data
    tty: true
    env_file:
        - ./docker.env
    entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh

php-fpm-symfony:
    <<: *default-container
    container_name: php-fpm-symfony

php-fpm-laravel:
    <<: *default-container
    container_name: php-fpm-laravel
```

References:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#References

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150782/using-yaml-with-variables